# Set the height of a div to its parents height

Tags: html, css

I have `div` "linkButton" which has a input field. I am not able to set the height for this `div`. the main `div` height should be as per the content. I don't want to hard code any height for this `div`.

I have created a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/v2hMm/80/

***note**: red color `div`'s height should be same as parent content and **">"** symbol should be in middle.*

```
 <div class="scrolldiv">
<div class="content" id="1">

  <div class="leftColumn">

  <div class="show" id="capInfo">

    <div class="label1">
      Apple CAP Contacts:
    </div>

    <div class="label2">
      <p>
        CAP Lead:
        <span class="LeadName">
          Keshab Patro
        </span>
        <span class="LeadEmail">
          kpatro@apple.com
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="lable3">
      <p>
        Verification Lead:
        <span class="vLeadName">
          Siva Rama Kiran Yanamandra
        </span>
        <span class="vLeadEmail">
          syanamandra@apple.com
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

  </div>

  <div class="rightColumn">

    <div class="rightGroup">

      <div class="groupproto">

        <p>
          <span class="protocolname show">
            PROTOCOL BY NAG ON 25/10
          </span>

          <span class="date_class show">
            OCT 28 - 31, 2013
          </span>
        </p>

      </div>

      <div class="statusClass hidden">
      </div>

      <div class="approvedFinding show">
      </div>

      <div class="closedFinding show">
      </div>

      <div class="verifiedFinding show">
      </div>

      <div class="lasActivity show">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="linkButton">

      <input type="button" class="lplinkbutton" value="&gt;" onclick="top.openPageURL('Pushinfolet?id=101693&amp;proc=104180&amp;flag=1&amp;emd=2&amp;accessflag=2&amp;edit_flag=Y&amp;wrapper=no')">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<Style>
      html{
      min-height: 100%;
      }
      .headingsection {
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 23px;
      padding-bottom: 5;
      padding-top: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
      }
      body {
      min-height: 100%;
      font-family: "Avenir Next", "Avenir", "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif !important;
      }
      .mycustcls{
      background-color:  white;
      padding-left:  5;
      }
      .sectionheader{
      background-color:  rgba(173, 172, 172, 0.94);
      border:  2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
      padding-left: 3px;
      color:  white;
      font-weight:  500;
      font-size:  15px;
      }
      .sectionspacer{
      height:20;
      }
      .sectionrows{
      background-color:  rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.93);
      padding:  10;
      padding-right: 0;
      overflow:  hidden;
      }
      .colsheader{
      height:  auto; 
      color:  white;
      font-weight:  500;
      font-size:  14px;
      float:  left;
      }
      .sectioncols{
      width:  300px; 
      height:  auto; 
      float:  left;
      color:  black;
      font-weight:  normal;
      font-size:  13px;
      }
      .mainsection{
      padding:10px;
      }
      .anotherspacer{
      background-color:  rgba(231, 231, 231, 0.72);
      }
      .rowseparator{
      border: 2px solid #CFCFCF;
      }
      .content { clear: both; font-size: 13px;}
      .Separator {border-top: 2px solid #B8B8B8;}
      .date_class { float:right; }
      .rightGroup { float: left; width:80%;}
      .linkbutton{float: right;width: 30;border:0;  max-height: 200px;}
      .anchor{cursor:pointer;font-weight:500;}
      .lplinkbutton{
      float: right;
      cursor:pointer;
      border:0;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 15;
      background-color: red; 
      width : 30px
      }
      .scrolldiv{
      overflow-x: auto;
      background-color  : rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.93);
      color: black;
      border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      }
      .colfacility_id,.colfacility_name{
      font-weight:600;
      text-decoration:underline;
      }
      .colfacility_id,.colfacility_local_name,.colfacility_address,.colcity,.collongitude{width:500px;padding-top:2px;}
      .colprotocol_name{
      font-weight:500;
      margin-left: 50px;
      width:500px;
      }
      .hidden{display:none;}
      .colname{font-weight:600;}
      .colfacility_address.colfacility_local_name,.colname{padding-top:5px; width: 235px;}
      .offlineclass{width:170px;color:black;font-size:  13px;} 
      .downloadasmnt{
      width: 73px;
      height: 29;
      border: 1px solid rgb(49, 120, 153);
      border-radius: 6;
      background-color: rgba(173, 172, 172, 0.94);
      color: white;
      font-weight: 500;
      }
      .datefloat{
      color: #666;
      font-size: 12px;
      }
      .datefloat,.offlineclass{
      font-weight:normal;
      float:right;
      }
      /*div.tt_upcoming.sectionheader{
      background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.93);
      color: black; 
      border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      }*/
      .sectionheader u.anchor{
      text-decoration:none;
      font-size: 17;
      margin-left: 6;
      }
      .protocoldate{
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid;
      }
      .tt_upcoming.sectionheader{
      background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.93) !important;
      color: black !important;
      }
      .leftColumn { float: left; width: 40%; padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;}
      .rightColumn { float: right; width: 50%; padding:0;}
      .rightColumn .rightGroup { padding-top: 10px; }
      .label1, .protocolname { font-weight: 500; }
      .content p { margin: 5px 0;}
      .groupproto { line-height: 0; padding-top: 4px;}
      .show{ display: block;}
      .groupproto { border-bottom: 1px solid #5C5C5C; margin-bottom:5px; }
      .label1 { text-decoration:underline; }
      .lasActivity ul { padding-left: 18px !important;}

</style>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I couldn't acces it, but now i can.

Comment: i put the CSS as well.

Comment: Your left column has a height of 99px, whereas your right column has a height of 30px. Your input tag's parent container (class lplinkbutton) has height of 16px. The height of each of these appears to be dictated by the content. You probably want to reorganise your right column, or consider making the button another column in the overall container

Answer (score 1):

set the `position` of your input to `absolute` then you can get the full height with `top:0; bottom:0;` and put input on the right side with `right:0;`, you need to set the parent `position` to `relative` too.

edit these classes:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/v2hMm/83/)

```
.lplinkbutton {
cursor: pointer;
border: 0;
font-weight: 500;
background-color: red;

/* added */
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 20px;
}

.scrolldiv {
position: relative;   /* added  */
overflow-x: auto;
background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.93);
color: black;
border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```